# Is it OK if I add dynamically google ads on mobile site?

Tags: google-adsense

I own a site which is a wall. Is it OK if I add google ads as the user scrolls down and new content is loaded, in the mobile view?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: It's fine with me.